# Redimensionar array

Tags: php, array

Tenho a seguinte dúvida, por exemplo

```
<?php
$cesta = array("laranja", "banana", "melancia", "morango");
$fruta = array_pop($cesta);
print_r($cesta);
?>
```

o *array* inicial vai da posição 0 até a 3, quando eu faço `array_pop` ele fica da posição 0 até a 2, porém se eu adicionar um novo elemento as posições do *array* serão, (0,1,2,4). Há alguma forma de colocar as posições como (0,1,2,3) excluindo um elemento e adicionando outro em seguida?

Comment: Como você inseriu o novo elemento? Testei com `$cesta[] = "maçã"` e `array_push($cesta, "maçã")` e em ambos os casos "maçã" foi inserido no índice 3.

Comment: sério? to inserindo diretamente com $cesta[]="maçã"

Comment: E como você concluiu que foi inserido no índice 4?

Comment: Reforçando o comentário do @AndersonCarlosWoss veja o teste: http://ideone.com/PgiTwi

Comment: Esse é só um exemplo que tem no site php.net, no meu caso conclui pois quando faço print_r(array), do indice 7 ele pula para o 12.

Comment: Tem como colocar esse código na pergunta?

Comment: O problema é quando vc remove um elemento do 'meio' do array e quebra a sequencia do indice?

Comment: Acho que identifiquei o problema, eu coloquei uma variavel global para indicar a posição do array porem nao estava setando seu valor

Answer (score 0):

Se a quebra da sequencia do índice é o problema como no código abaixo:

```
<?php

   $cesta = array("laranja", "banana", "melancia", "morango");
   unset($cesta[1]);
   $cesta[] = "novo";
```

Pode criar uma nova variável e resetar os índices usando a função [`array_merge()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php) ela irá criar um novo array com o array passado como argumento. Pode obter o mesmo resultado com [`array_values()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-values.php)

[**Exemplo - ideone**](http://ideone.com/PZgj06)

```
<?php

   $cesta = array("laranja", "banana", "melancia", "morango");
   unset($cesta[1]);
   print_r($cesta);
   $cesta[] = "novo";
   print_r($cesta);

   $novo = array_merge($cesta);

   print_r($novo);
```

Comment: Eu ia citar agora o `array_values`, acho que ela é bem mais rápida que a `array_merge` para esta finalidade.

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss acho que é o contrário: http://ideone.com/PlLH54 pelo menos nesse teste.

Comment: Fiz testes usando o `microtime` e chegava a dar 10x mais rápido, mas acredito não ser muito confiável o resultado.